# How can I fill gaps/cracks in vinyl floors due to incorrect underlay at install - can anything be done to prevent further damage?

Tags: repair, vinyl-flooring

I had professional installers put down the vinyl flooring, but I purchased the wrong underlay and it wasn't flagged. And it's too thick/not rigid enough - so there are now areas where the vinyl is cracking and separating.

Are there any repair options I have to fill these gaps?

I know I need to pull up the floors and replace the underlay but I can't afford to do so and am hoping to get advice on a passable interim solution.

The floors are 600sq ft and there are probably 3 areas that need repair.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/MMmeTzUJ96buAop18

Comment: This is what vinyl flooring does. I was excited about it when it came out about 10 years ago, but frankly, I no longer use it at all, leaning back on the laminate again. Laminate is water weak, but vinyl chips like this just by regular use in only a few years. No, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: eeeps that's such a disappointment. So no fillers will work even for the short term to keep it from getting worse?